# Prepending data to a FlatList always shows the first child

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-native-listview

this is our FlatList, say hello:

```
<FlatList
    data={this.state.dates}
...
/>
```

we feed it with the following dates:

```
this.state = {
    dates: [
        '21/06/2019',
        '22/06/2019',
        '23/06/2019',
    ]
};
```

then when the visible date changes (`onViewableItemsChanged`), if we end up to the first item (**21/06/2019**), we prepend data, so that the new state becomes:

```
dates: [
        '18/06/2019',
        '19/06/2019',
        '20/06/2019',
        '21/06/2019',
        '22/06/2019',
        '23/06/2019',
]
```

### The Problem:

right after we **prepend** the data, instead of STILL seeing **21/06/2019** (which was the date when the prepend took place) we now see **19/06/2019**.

That's because below the hood, **21/06/2019** used to be index 0, but after the prepend, index 0 corresponds to **19/06/2019**.

### What we want:

I'm trying to make it so that the **day remains the same** after prepending data.

Please don't tell me to use `scrollToPosition` because that's a hack really, not the solution.
Is there any good solution to that problem?

Thank you

Comment: Because you're changing the indexes, I don't see how could you do that without `scrollToIndex` (or, this would be even more hacky). If your items have the same height, the scroll will be fast, and you may use `getItemLayout` to optimize the rendering.

Comment: Have your found any proper solution ? I am facing the same issue in my project.

Comment: No, nothing so far

Comment: @SudoPlz did you find any solution to this?

Comment: Not really, so we ended up creating our own list component on react-native which I'm trying to convince our management to allow us to release open-source.

Answer (score 2):

There is an undocumented prop [maintainVisibleContentPosition](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/902541e87473596bb0a930e397d34140488521bc/Libraries/Components/ScrollView/ScrollView.js#L189) on `ScrollView` that do what you want, but unfortunately it's not working on android

I found another workaround by keep latest y offset with [onScroll](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/3915c0fa6178fbb8aa9b8bd54881cfdbde8fde70/Libraries/Components/ScrollView/ScrollView.js#L454) and also save content height before and after adding new items with [onContentSizeChange](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/3915c0fa6178fbb8aa9b8bd54881cfdbde8fde70/Libraries/Components/ScrollView/ScrollView.js#L473) and calculate the difference of content height, and set new y offset to the latest y offset + content height difference!

I've opened an [issue on github](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/25239) also, but there is not any complete solution yet
Thanks to [sgtpepper43](https://github.com/sgtpepper43) for undocumented iOS solution

Comment: Thanks for reassuring me I'm no the only one facing that issue.
Looks like someone will have to dive into the Android code and implement that flag for Android as well.

Comment: I tested `maintainVisibleContentPosition` on `iOS`. But this property `only` works if you `append` data. if you `prepend` data, it does `not` work.

Answer (score 2):

that `maintainVisibleContentPosition` does not work if you **prepend data** while you are at a **scroll position of 0** (all the way to the top). It does work if you are prepending while **not a the top**. Even scroll Y of 1 would be enough.

check [this](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/25239#issuecomment-731100372)

Unfortunately this still an issue even in `React Native 0.63.3` and has not been solved.

Answer (score 1):

Leaving this here, since it took me a while to get a working solution/ workaround to this problem that doesn't leave a bad taste in my mouth: prepopulate the array with empty data, and then use the `scrollToIndex` method.

```
this.state = {
  dates: [
    '',
    '',
    '',
    '21/06/2019',
    '22/06/2019',
    '23/06/2019',
  ]
};
```

And then:

```
<FlatList
    data={this.state.dates}
    ref={flatListRef}
    getItemLayout={(data, index) => (
      {length: ITEM_HEIGHT, offset: ITEM_HEIGHT * index, index}
    )}
...
/>
```

inside your componentDidMount:

```
const startingIndex = 4
flatListRef.current.scrollToIndex({index: startingIndex, animated: false, viewPosition: 0})
```

Comment: That's true, but is there a reasonable amount by which you could prepopulate the data (i.e. would you expect a user to go back further than 2 years, for instance?)

Answer (score 1):

There's a library: https://github.com/GetStream/react-native-bidirectional-infinite-scroll that allows you to both preprend or append data and preserve scroll position

It's basically an extension over the FlatList and supports all the props available for a plain FlatList

From their example usage tutorial: https://dev.to/vishalnarkhede/react-native-how-to-build-bidirectional-infinite-scroll-32ph#%F0%9F%96%A5-tutorial-chat-ui-with-bidirectional-infinite-scroll

It looks like it would be enough to just prepend that data to the top exactly like you're trying to do

Comment: Looks cool, but won't work in Expo managed workflow.